# Interactive boolean prompts in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: filter, prompt, reportbuilder3.0

I added 5 Boolean prompts to my report.  The 5 prompts allow the user to filter the data by (1) Group, (2) Region, (3) City, (4) Area, and (5) Branch.  The default value is "false" on all them except (1) Group; which is true.  Is it possible to make these prompts interactive?  What I would like to do is if the user selects (2) Region as true, then any one that is true (1) Group would change to false.  I only want the user to be able to select 1 prompt as true.  Is this possible?  Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.  If I can't do this, I can always make a drop down for these values.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is partially possible. Both the Available values and the Default values can be expressions that refer to previous parameters. However, this only works in one direction. In other words, the first parameter cannot refer to the subsequent ones in its expressions.

Comment: @StevenWhite...........Thanks for the explanation.  That is not going to work.  The user was thinking of checkboxes in an Excel form where if you click one, the other ones get unchecked.  They may have to settle for a drop down list with only 1 selection.....Thanks again